# InvokeMember with XPath

Tags: .net

My purpose is to click a button automatically in a webBrowser. I am collecting clickables in the source code, and according to these clickables' xpath values, I want to invoke member click.

For invokeMember method, I can use clickable id, but instead, I need to use Xpath. Do you have any ideas?

Here is some code: (I am using c# .NET)

```
 HtmlElement element = browser.Document.GetElementById(ClickableId);
 element = browser.Document.GetElementById(ClickableId);
 element.InvokeMember("click");
```

I mean; I want to do this operation with clickable xPath?

Answer (score 0):

From what i've been reading, it is not possible to query a WebBrowser control with XPath.

You might find the following questions useful:

[Navigation and WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535252/navigation-and-webbrowser-control)

[Get all elements matching an XPath expression in a webbrowser document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431090/get-all-elements-matching-an-xpath-expression-in-a-webbrowser-document)